# SLIM framework how to assign conditions to route callback function

Tags: callback, routes, conditional-statements, slim

I have a route defined in my Slim app like so:

```
$app->get('/marcas/:id', 'getMarcas');
```

My callback function is defined as:

```
function getMarcas($id) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE id=:id";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $marcas = $stmt->fetchObject();  
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($mrcas); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

}

How can I apply a route condition like:

```
->conditions(array('id' => '[0-9]{2,}'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign conditions exactly the way you guessed. See the Route Conditions documentation for details: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Conditions

Comment: What about when the route has optional route parameters, like
$app->get('/marcas(/:carrocaria(/:ano))', 'getMarcas'); ?

Comment: Just make the regex an optional match: `conditions('arg' => '[a-zA-Z]{0,}')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:firstName/:lastName', $callable)
->conditions(array('lastName' => '[0-9]{2,}'));
```

with calling of get/post